# How to arrange citations numbering in order of their presence in text?

Tags: bibtex, formatting, natbib

I have code like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{turabian-thesis}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{colortbl,dcolumn}
\newcommand\hmmax{0}
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Fermi arcs are reported \citep{naylor2016monolayer,zhou2017role,zhou2015large,zhou2017large}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refferences4}
\end{document}
```

this gives me out : Fermi arcs are reported [31, 20, 32, 33],
here what I want is the numbering should appear [20, 31, 32, 33].
Is there a latex code that helps to correct this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you have a particular reason for employing the `ieeetr` bibliography style at present? I see you employ the `natbib` citation management package. Are you free to switch from the `ieeetr` style to the `unsrtnat` style?

Comment: ieeetr gives the right reference formatting , I am flexible as long as I can get citations in squarebracket []. I have this things written in overleaf and huge compilation of different chapters there. I tried unsrtnat keeping other things unchanged, but did not help.

Comment: Is this example the first place these references are called, or are they called earlier as well?  For unsrt, the number is determined by the first time the reference is called.  It's not clear if it's the original numbering that is bothering you, or the fact that once they are numbered, you are calling them in a particular order that you would like changed.  In the later case, I am not sure there is anything you can do except reorder things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`?

You should also try turning off your other packages to see if they are interfering.

Comment: tried but unsuccessfull